# update module on import to python interpreter

Tags: python-import, rebuild, spyder

**In short**

How to force python interpreter to load the most up-to-date code version of my module everytime I make some changes in the module code?

Or at least reload the last modified version by typing

```
>>> from myModule import *
```

into console, without necessity to restart whole python console and setup everything again and again anytime I make some changes? This is extremely unpleasant behavior for debugging.

**--------- LONGER STORY -----------**

I **tried to delete the .pyc file**, and import it again - but it has no effect. It does't even create .pyc file again - so I expect it completely ignore my "import" command if the module is already loaded.

this also does not help:

```
>>> mymodule.myfunc()    # the old version
>>> del myModule         # unload mymodle from python conole / interpeter
...                  # now I removed .pyc
...                  # now I make some modifications in mymodule.myfunc() code   
>>> mymodule.myfunc()    # module is unknonwn, ... OK
>>> import myModule      # try to load modified version
>>> mymodule.myfunc()    # stil the old version :(((((, How it can remember?
```

I have tried also Spyder where is this feature called **"User Module Deleter (UMD)"**
http://pythonhosted.org/spyder/console.html#reloading-modules-the-user-module-deleter-umd
which I thought should do exactly this, but it seem it doesn't (Yes, I checked that it is turned on).

Maybe I'm missing something - can somebody explain me how is it supposed to be used?

Is this somehow affected by the fact that the imported module is not in "Working directory" but in PYTHONPATH ?

Comment: OK, I just found that 

        **reload( mymodule )** 

does thet job. But still, 1) is it possible to make it somehow automatic?  2) What UMD good for, if not this?

Comment: relaod is not working for me. Im changing a file in the editor and then save it. then I reload(ModuleName) in the console and running the updated method from the module, and I get the old method. only running the module from the editor (F5) actually update the module. any advice?

Comment: @idoda Same for me.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Spyder dev here) I think at the moment you are not able to reload a module directly in the console (but we are considering to change this in the future).

The idea about **UMD** is that it will reload your modules but only **if** you run a file from the **editor** that imports them. It doesn't work if you want to reload them directly in the console.

Let's say you developed a module, then you are probably using it in a different script that (most likely) you'll be writing in our editor and send it to run to our console. **UMD** is a little bit of magic that reloads it for you when that happens.

Comment: Hi, I researched this issue for a little bit and it seems there is no reliable way to update a module from the Python interpreter. That's why we provide our *UMD* and to use it you just need to make any call to your module from a script

Comment: How do you enable UMD? Is it enabled by default?

Comment: Yes, it's enabled by default, but you can disable it in `Tools > Preferences > Console > Advanced settings > User Module Reloader`

Comment: On Spyder3: Preferences => Python Interpreter => Enable UMR

Comment: Spyder3 doesn't work for me. I change one thing in `functions.py` and try to import them again but the old code is run. It's very annoying

Comment: @Peter.k, you need to run your file with `F5` to get your changes updated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe useful for others. In Spyder 3.0.0, the modules can be reloaded by,

Tools -> Update modules names list.

It worked for me.