# Python not importing the updated version of my module

Tags: python, python-import, spyder

`mypackage` includes these lines:

```
x = 1
y = 2
```

Now I am trying to run `foo.py` that does something like the following:

```
import mypackage as mp
x = mp.x #works
y = mp.y #does not work
```

When I run `foo.py`, line 3 triggers the following error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'y'

The old version of mypackage only had x and not y. So I've tried updating it. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module) solution. I've tried actually running the package to regenerate the `.pyc` file, but no dice.

How do I get my new version of `foo.py` to import the new version of `mypackage`?

Comment: The first step is to see what package it's actually importing.  `print(mp.__file__)` will show you this.

Comment: If in doubt, restart the interpreter. But `reload` should have worked.

Comment: I'm running Python in Spyder, and simply closing and restarting Spyder fixed my issue. Should I post this as the solution?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17349834/10553976